# save video in python from bytes

Tags: python, rest, opencv

i have 2 microservices, **A** is written in java and sending a video in the form of **bytes[ ]** to **B** which is written in python.

**B** is doing some treatement over the video using openCV and this command in particular

```
 stream = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
```

the command works fine when provided by a streaming or a ready local video, but when i give it my **request.data** which java is sending it says

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

so my question is :

is there any way to save a video to disk from that bytes i'm receiving from java or can i just give the bytes to **cv2.capture** ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to read a video file as binary data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686698/python-how-to-read-a-video-file-as-binary-data)

Comment: no it's not efficient as i don't have a small video, reading it byte by byte is not good

Comment: so you want to save the stream video file ?

Comment: i have a byte array sent to python from java that i want to give to open cv through the command cv2.capture as it dosnt accept byte arrays i'm looking for a way to either save the video to disk then give it to her or try to configure her or something so that it accepts byte arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a slight improvement to your own solution: using the `with` context-manager closes the file for you even if something unexpected happens:

```
FILE_OUTPUT = 'output.avi'

# Checks and deletes the output file
# You cant have a existing file or it will through an error
if os.path.isfile(FILE_OUTPUT):
    os.remove(FILE_OUTPUT)

# opens the file 'output.avi' which is accessable as 'out_file'
with open(FILE_OUTPUT, "wb") as out_file:  # open for [w]riting as [b]inary
    out_file.write(request.data)
```

Comment: and i delete the close part ?

Comment: Exactly - as soon as you "leave" the with-statement, it closes the file automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem like this :

```
FILE_OUTPUT = 'output.avi'

# Checks and deletes the output file
# You cant have a existing file or it will through an error
if os.path.isfile(FILE_OUTPUT):
    os.remove(FILE_OUTPUT)

out_file = open(FILE_OUTPUT, "wb") # open for [w]riting as [b]inary
out_file.write(request.data)
out_file.close()
```