# Best way to convert image,videos to string format

Tags: python, algorithm, image, encryption

I want to store some of my personal images and videos in an encrypted format and want to develop the python script by myself. As the encryption which I am using requires input in string format what are the most efficient way to convert images and videos to string format?

I have considered using base64 but it won't be a practical and most efficient solution due to its increased size.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried converting an image to string using python's pillow module.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(r"*****\naruto.png")#The full path to the image

output = BytesIO()
image.save(output, format="png")
image_as_string = output.getvalue()

print(image_as_string[:20])
```

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1oLr.jpg)

Output:

b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x05\xa0'

This worked for me. I am a beginner to programming. So other suggestions will also be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17686777/15821025 You can refer this.

Comment: No, this is not right. When you use `Image.open()` you decode the compressed PNG image into memory and it is essentially an uncompressed array of pixels. When you do `Image.save()` you recompress the image back to more-or-less exactly the same as it was on disk in the first place - so there is no point doing any of this. You might as well just open the image in **binary** mode with the standard `open()`  and `read()` it. You will get the same. If you don't believe me, go to https://hexed.it and load your original PNG and you will see it is the same as the *"string"* you have created.